# If the product of two idempotents is idempotent, must the two idempotents commute?

Tags: ring-theory, semigroups

It is a basic fact that when two idempotents $e,f$ in a semigroup $S$ commute, then $ef$ is an idempotent. Is the converse true? Is it true for idempotents in rings?

Comment: What do you mean by converse? If $ef$ is idempotent and $e$ and $f$ are idempotent, then $ef=fe$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. In $M_2(\mathbb{C})$, let 
$$
e=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}, \ \ 
f=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So 
$$
e^2=e, \ \ f^2=f, \ \ ef=f, \ \ fe=e.
$$

Comment: Thank you. May I ask how you obtained this example? The form of this answers makes me think it wasn't picked at random.

Comment: I usually work with operators on a Hilbert space. In the case of projections, i.e. Selfadjoint idempotents, it is true that selfadjointness of a product of selfadjoints implies that they commute. So I just looked for the easiest non-selfadjoint idempotent, which is my $f$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the semi-group of matrix $2\times 2$ with real entries and $A:=\pmatrix{0&1\\\ 0& 1}$, $B=\pmatrix{1&0\\\ 0&0}$. Then $A^2=A$, $B^2=B$, $AB=0$ but $BA=\pmatrix{0&1\\\ 0&0}\neq AB$.